# Define constant based on BOOL

Tags: ios, macros, constants, retina-display

In my iOS app I have a constants.h class where I define kBorderWidth. For retina displays I would like this to be .5 so that borders are 1 pixel thick, and on non-retina displays I want it to be 1 so that it remains one pixel thick and not less. This is my code right now:

```
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0))

#if __IS_RETINA == 1
    #define kBorderWidth .5
#else
    #define kBorderWidth 1
#endif
```

That compiles just fine but results in kBorderWidth being 1. How can I fix this so that it accomplishes that I want it to do?

Comment: While I agree with Michael's answer, and in general better to use singleton instead of #define for such case, you might want to use something like `#define kBorderWidth (1.0 / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale)` which should provide 1px even for futuretina displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I settled upon was the one suggested by Lanorkin which is to define it like this:

```
#define kBorderWidth (1.0 / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale)
```

That being future proof and simple as well as working within the constants.h file that I have already setup.

Answer (score 0):

Your "`#define`" Macro:

```
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0))
```

defines some code that executes at *run time*, not at compile time.

Instead of doing:

```
#if __IS_RETINA == 1
    #define kBorderWidth .5
#else
    #define kBorderWidth 1
#endif
```

You should be setting a run time variable, such as:

```
static CGFloat gBorderWidth; // at the top of your .m file
```

or a property:

```
@property (readwrite) CGFloat borderWidth;
```

And then set it in your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear methods:

```
if(([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0)))
{
    self.borderWidth = 0.5f;
} else {
    self.borderWidth = 1.0f;
}
```

Now that I realize you want to make this available to a number of view controllers (e.g. because it was originally in "`constants.h`"), why not create a decorator *singleton* class, which is always in existence for the life of your app and can control the appearance of your app via exposed properties, such as the "`borderWidth`" one.

So you could access it via something like:

```
 AppearanceUtilityClass *appearance = [AppearanceUtilityClass sharedInstance];
 CGFloat borderWidth = appearance.borderWidth;
```

Comment: I started a similar answer then realized that `kBorderWidth` is being defined in a constants.h file meaning that variable should be available in any class that imports the .h. Your solution only works for a single .m file.

Comment: bleah… that's disgusting.  Okay.  I'll try to rework my answer a bit.